# Dagger2 aggregate Providers of same base type into Array or Collection?

Tags: dagger-2

I have a lot of Objects that are of interface `Foo`. So I have a lot of providers of `Foo`'s, no issue there.

My issue is that I have an object that needs a collection of foo's (All the Foo's). Consider the following:

```
@Module
@AppScope
public class AppModule {
    //OTHER PROVIDERS MY FOO'S DEPEND ON OMITTED 
    @Provides
    AaFoo provideAaFoo(){
        return new AaFoo();
    }

    @Provides 
    BbFoo provideBbFoo(){
        return new BbFoo();
    }

    @Provides
    CcFoo providesCcFoo(Something something) {
        return new CcFoo(something);
    }

    //EVEN MORE KINDS OF FOO's...

    //Now I need to provide a thing that holds all Foo's
    //TODO: This pattern is horribly ugly!
    @Provides
    FooManager provideFooManager(
            AaFoo aa,
            BbFoo bb,
            CcFoo cc,
            ...) {//each time I make a foo I have to add; mention it here
        FooManager fooService = new FooManager();
        fooService.addFoo(aa);
        fooService.addFoo(bb);
        fooService.addFoo(cc);
        fooService.addFoo(dd); 
        ... //and I need to put it here, how nice it would be if this were a collection...
        return fooService;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can ask dagger to aggregate all foo's into a collection such that I can just pass that collection to my `provideRouteService` method? That way as I add more foo's everything just works?

Comment: It would be nice if provideFooManager could use varargs and dagger2 could somehow work with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the answer is in Multibindings(https://google.github.io/dagger//multibindings.html) and is really simple:

To convert the above simply:

1. Add @IntoSet to each of my Foo providers.
2. Have them all return Foo's instead of the subtype
3. Have the FooProvider take a Set

Example:

```
@Module
@AppScope
public class AppModule {
    //OTHER PROVIDERS MY FOO'S DEPEND ON OMITTED 
    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    Foo provideAaFoo(){
        return new AaFoo();
    }

    @Provides 
    @IntoSet
    Foo provideBbFoo(){
        return new BbFoo();
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    Foo providesCcFoo(Something something) {
        return new CcFoo(something);
    }

    //EVEN MORE KINDS OF FOO's...

    //Now I need to provide a thing that holds all Foo's
    //TODO: This pattern isn't ugly any more!
    @Provides
    FooManager provideFooManager(
            Set<Foo> foos) {
        return new FooManager(foos);
    }
}
```

Also annotated FooManager's constructor with @Inject. Much clearer!